Ignoring request for not matching predefined routes
I have some Sanic Python app code where following routes are defined:

def create_inspector(app):
    inspector = Sanic(configure_logging=False)
    inspector.config['KEEP_ALIVE'] = False
    inspector.app = app
    inspector.add_route(render_status, '/')
    inspector.add_route(get_status, '/api/status')
    return inspector


But when I hit the endpoint with endpoint.
curl -k http://localhost:9504/api/123

I get following traceback in app log.
  File "/opt/product/4.0.0.1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 546, in handle_request
    handler, args, kwargs, uri = self.router.get(request)
  File "/opt/product/4.0.0.1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/router.py", line 344, in get
    return self._get(request.path, request.method, '')
  File "/opt/product/4.0.0.1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/router.py", line 393, in _get
    raise NotFound('Requested URL {} not found'.format(url))
sanic.exceptions.NotFound: Requested URL /api/123 not found

Is it possible to trap all the invalid endpoints and send them to 404 (resource not found) status?

Take a look at the docs:
from sanic.exceptions import NotFound

@app.exception(NotFound, SomeCustomException)
async def ignore_404s(request, exception):
    return text("Yep, I totally found the page: {}".format(request.url))


I had to modify my code as follows
def create_inspector(app):
    inspector = Sanic(configure_logging=False)
    inspector.config['KEEP_ALIVE'] = False
    inspector.app = app
    inspector.add_route(render_status, '/')
    inspector.add_route(not_found, r"<path:path>") # this was added here
    inspector.add_route(get_status, '/api/status')
    return inspector

async def not_found(request, path): #new fn was added to handle non existent path
    return json('Not Found', status=404)

